# Setting GitVersion for prerelease

Tags: gitversion

I've created a new project on GitHub that I plan to deploy to NuGet.org.

I want to make the initial releases 'prerelease' (building through AppVeyor off of the master branch).

I used `gitversion init` to generate the GitVersionConfig.yaml. This process suggested it would create a verbose file with most things commented out, but in reality it just created this:

```
mode: ContinuousDeployment
branches: {}
```

What do I need to change to get the desired result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `GitVersion.exe /showconfig` to see the effective configuration, we are moving away from creating the template and using `GitVersion init` as a configuration tool.

But the config you want is:

```
branches:
  master:
    tag: beta
```

Comment: I get a SyntaxErrorException trying to use that config

Comment: Actually, I think it might have been whitespace issues - nevermind!

Comment: Note that in `git bash`, you will need to use `GitVersion.exe -showconfig` (a hyphen for the argument instead of a slash).